# Size of minimal generating set of $C_3 \times S_3$ and $C_3 \rtimes S_3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What's the minimal size of the generating set for $C_3 \times S_3$ and $C_3 \rtimes S_3$?

A minimal generating set of $S_3$ is size $2$, and a minimal generating set of $C_3$ is size $1$, so we can bound this by $2+1=3$. They are non-cyclic so it must be of size $2$ or more.

How can we determine which of these is the correct value for each?

Comment: What have you tried??

Comment: That's four questions - all straightforward. Have you thought about them at all? A group with a generating set of size $1$ is cyclic and a group with an empty generating set is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a easy question for a beginner to answer.

Hints.

The group $C_3\times S_3$ has a generating set of size $2$:
$$
\langle(e,(123)),(a,(12))\rangle,
$$
where $\langle a\rangle=C_3$ and $a^3=e$.

The group $G=C_3\rtimes S_3$  does not have a generating set of size $2$.
Indeed, this group has a normal subgroup $A$ isomorphic to $C_3\times C_3$. All elements not lying in $A$ are of order $2$. Now let $x, y$ be a generating set $G$.
Next consider three cases:
a) $x,y\in A$;
b) $x\in A$, $y\not\in A$;
c) $x,y\not\in A$.
Verify that in each of these cases $|\langle x,y\rangle|=9\text{ or }6$.

I think you will find the generating set of three elements by yourself. In fact, you have found it.

**PS.**
Two words about the group $C_3\rtimes S_3$. It seems to be a group for which the action of $S_3$ on $C_3$ is given by a nontrivial homomorphism $S_3\to\operatorname{Aut}(C_3)$. There is exactly one such homomorphism.

Comment: But there are two groups with structure $C_3 \rtimes S_3$ and the one with trivial action is $2$-generated.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Of course, the one corresponding to a trivial action is generated by two elements - this is the first part of my answer. In the second part I mean the non-trivial action $S_3$ on $C_3$. There is exactly one such group. But I'll clarify my answer.